# How to pass values from controller to javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My controller queries the database and organizes some values. I need to pass these values to javascript(JQuery) which use the values to fullfill UI features. How to pass values from controller to javascript???

Comment: Have you tried to do it via Ajax and JSON?

Answer (score 2):

1. Pass data through your view.
2. Use Ajax. Then pass all you need from respond_to block, or through rjs file
3. Organize Comet server. And push javascript right from your controllers. (for example, http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/)